# What's a faster alternative to BufferedReader's readLine() method?

Tags: java, performance, io, bufferedreader, bufferedinputstream

`readLine()` returns a String, but what I need are the `ASCII` characters of the characters of each string on each line.

E.g.

ABCDE
XYZ

I need the ASCII characters of A, B, C, D, E, and also X, Y, Z, but separately. Currently, I'm using `BufferedReader`'s `readLine` method, then loop through the length of the string and using `String.charAt()` to retrieve the character at each position. It's then trivial to convert characters to bytes.

I figured it must be expensive to create strings from bytes, then convert back into bytes. I tried writing my own solution using `FileChannel`:

```
        FileChannel f = FileChannel.open(Paths.get("file.txt"));
        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(10000);
        bytesRead = 0;
        byte[] chunk = new byte[10000];

        while (bytesRead != -1) {
            bytesRead = f.read(buffer);
            buffer.flip();

            while (buffer.hasRemaining()) {
                buffer.get(chunk, 0, bytesRead);
                processChunk(chunk);
            }

            buffer.clear();
        }
```

I don't know why but this turned out to be slower than `BufferedReader`'s `readLine()` method.

I found this answer: [Why is the performance of BufferedReader so much worse than BufferedInputStream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14301150/why-is-the-performance-of-bufferedreader-so-much-worse-than-bufferedinputstream) and I was wondering if `BufferedInputStream` could be of help to me.

Speed is of utmost priority for this!

Comment: I’m not sure what “ASCII characters of A, B, C, D, E” means, since ABCDE are already ASCII characters.  Perhaps you meant the ASCII *codes* of those characters, as byte values?  Perhaps you should just read them from a BufferedInputStream?

Comment: Yes sorry, I meant the numeric codes.

Comment: @VGR So I tried using a BIS and I'm getting TLE on my assignment submission page (online grader). https://repl.it/repls/FloralwhiteIdenticalAtoms It seems that BufferedReader's readLine() is still way way faster for reading lines. Is there a way to read a line (until a newline character) without first building a string from it, because ultimately I want the bytes, and not the string representation?

Comment: Don”t use Strings at all.  Just read bytes one by one from the InputStream until you get a byte whose value is -1 or 10 (the codepoint value of `\n`).